# Android: How to clear activity stack from widget

Tags: android, android-activity, widget

Is there a way to clear activity stack from widget?

I have following situation:
From widget user presses button what starts new activity A. Next user move from A to new activity B. After that he presses home button which takes him back to home screen. Now if he presses button again, he will be moved directly to the activity B.

I thought ACTIVITY_FLAG_CLEAR_TOP would help, but it didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does activity A start activity B? If so you can start it with the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY flag to specify not to put B in the history stack.

Comment: But will BACK button work to move back from activity B to activity A?

Comment: Yes, you will go back to activity A because A is in the history stack.

Comment: and if there will be another activity C from B ?

Comment: If you tell android FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY for B, from C you'll go back to A.  The idea is by specifying FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY for B, you're telling Android not to keep track of that activity. Once you leave B it will be gone (no going back to it).

Comment: Ok, in my opinion it's better to move from activity C back to A when BACK button pressed, than to move to the top of activity stack from widget :-) Thank you ;-)